# Firebase makes Flutter App build crashes on it's own library code

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to build an app with firebase services, and try these steps many times, including in a fresh new project just to test, but I think there's a problem with the library:

I am running

```
 flutterfire configure
```

By terminal on the root folder of the project, then selecting one of the projects, selecting all the available platforms ( android, ios, macos, web), then agreeing with the update of `android/build.gradle` and `android/app/build.gradle`

After that I've got :

```
Firebase configuration file lib/firebase_options.dart generated successfully with the following Firebase apps:
```

But just importing the libraries make the build crashes

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
```

The error I'm getting is this

```
: Error: '$throw' isn't a type.
../…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:120
        $throw coreNotInitialized();
        ^^^^^^
: Error: Expected ';' after this.
../…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:120
        $throw coreNotInitialized();
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: Expected an identifier, but got ')'.
../…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:120
Try inserting an identifier before ')'.

        $throw coreNotInitialized();
                                  ^
```

**The sample App is just this:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("My App")),
        body: const Center(child: Text("MyApp")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't have to import `firebase_core` in your dart file, it's for the other resources to use

Comment: It's what the documentation says: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initialization

Comment: I've always been using Manual Configuration hence I do not need to pass `options` parameter in `.initializeApp()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this workaround, I think there's a problem with the current library version or flutterfire but the next steps work for me:

I changed the versions of the firebase libaries for previous versions I had work with, run `flutter clean` and deleted the `Podfile.lock` and it now it's working

**NOT WORKING VERSIONS**

```
firebase_core: ^2.2.0
firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1
```

**WORKING VERSIONS**

```
firebase_core: ^1.1.0
firebase_messaging: ^9.1.3
```